# Different ways of declaring a resource bundle in JSF2.x

Tags: jsf, facelets, resourcebundle, jsf-2.2

I am working on JSF2.2 at my work place. My faces-config.xml has the resource bundle tag which helps me to assign a variable to a property file and use the variable in a EL.

```
   <resource-bundle>
    <base-name>properties.common</base-name>
    <var>prop</var>
   </resource-bundle>
```

I also found another way of achieving this by using the f:loadBundle tag like this

```
<f:loadBundle basename="properties.common" var="prop"/>
```

But this is a localized solution, meaning I would have to write this in every page.

1. Would this work if i define this in a template ? If yes, how do i achieve it.
2. Is there any other way that i can declare the resource globally with a variable to be used in an EL(like in the case of faces-config.xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Would this work if i define this in a template ?*

Yes.

---

> *If yes, how do i achieve it.*

Just do exactly as you said. Define it in a template.

---

> *Is there any other way that i can declare the resource globally with a variable to be used in an EL(like in the case of faces-config.xml)*

Put it in request map yourself in (post)constructor of a request scoped bean which is referenced in the view.

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("properties.common", facesContext.getViewRoot().getLocale());
externalContext.getRequestMap().put("prop", bundle);
```

It can even be referenced as a property of a request scoped bean and this guarantees construction of the bean even if it's not referenced elsewhere in the view.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what Iam looking for, see my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461307/jsf-2-external-resource-bundle

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("properties.common",facesContext.getViewRoot().getLocale());
externalContext.getRequestMap().put("prop", bundle);
```

thanks all...